# How to download file sent from nodejs server using $http get request

Tags: node.js, express

This is what i did so far in order to download file from server. The thing is that I dont know what to write inside the response function in order to make the file automatically download like most website downloads do. If i write `console.log(response)` I see the the file as string in my console.log I want to download it instead.

Client

```
function downloadFile(filePath) {
        return $http({
            url: '/download',
            method: "GET",
            params: { filePath: filePath }
        }).then((response) => {
            return response.data;
        }).catch(err => console.err);
    }

function fileDownload(filePath, fileExtension) {
        let filepath = filePath + '.' + fileExtension;
        downloadFile(filepath).then((response) => {

        });
    }
```

Server:

```
app.get('/download', (req, res) => {
        let file = path.join(__dirname, 'public/files' , req.query.filePath);
        res.download(file);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get('/download', (req, res) => {
    let file = path.join(__dirname, 'public/files' , req.query.filePath);

    let mime_type // check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Type
        , disposition // check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Disposition
        ;
    let header = { 
        'Content-Type': mime_type, 
        'Content-Disposition': disposition
    }

    let fReadStream = fs.createReadStream(file);
    fReadStream.on('open', (fd) => {
            res.writeHeader(200, header);
        }).pipe(res);
});
```

Comment: not working gives me `throw new Error('"value" required in setHeader("' + name + '", value)');`